# Pattern brush scale menu greyed out

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, brush

So I'm pretty noobish when it comes to Illustrator, but I can't tell what I'm doing wrong here. I've got this pattern brush on a path, and the path has some Width Points set on it, but I can't select Width Points as the source for the scale of the brush.

[image: Menu items greyed out]

Every menu item is greyed out, which okay, I don't have a tablet plugged in so I get why I can't use pressure etc. but I don't understand why it won't let me use Width Points.

(This is CS6, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width/Profile gets automatically set when you use the Width Tool on the Brush Path. It's not a setting you can alter by default.

Change the profile of your brush path, *then* Width/Profile will be available. It's basically there as a "reset to the profile" option. Without a profile, there's nothing to reset to.

Comment: I thought I was doing this but - I was double-clicking the brush to edit, which was getting rid of the profile information! You actually need to hit the edit brush button to do it.

Comment: Yes. Brushes can't contain a profile setting by default. You have to apply a profile, then edit the current brush.